# Change edit area background color

Tags: ckeditor

How to change the editing area background color using the ckeditor plugin "Div editing area" ?

With the "Iframe editing area" plugin, I use `contentsCss` which alter the body section like this, and it works fine :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('Description',
        {
            uiColor: '#a7bdea',
            width: 'auto',
            height: '150',
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
            contentsCss : body{ background : red}
        });
```

But it seems ckeditor ignores `contentsCss` with div area editing. Any ideas?

Comment: The [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) is a string (or an array of strings). And those strings are urls to stylesheet files. That's why CKEditor ignores your setting.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your code:

```
CKEDITOR.addCss(".cke_editable{background-color: red}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Brutal, yet working:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'divarea',
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.editable().setStyle( 'background-color', 'red' );
        }
    }
} );
```